# why the button is not calling the other method?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

i am new to iOS here is my code

```
    -(void)getImageV{
    internet *myClass = [[internet alloc]init];
    if ([myClass connectedToInternet]) {
    NSUInteger x =[_relatedOffers count];
    self.scrollViewTest.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x*172, _scrollViewTest.frame.size.height);

    for (int pos=0; pos<[_relatedOffers count]; pos++) {       

        NSLog(@"-------->%d",pos);
        UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        NSLog(@"------>%@",aButton);
        [aButton setTag:pos];
        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(pos*150, 0, 158, 70);
        buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(140, 90);
        aButton.frame = buttonFrame;       
        [self.relatedViewOffer addSubview:aButton];
        NSLog(@"-------->%@",aButton);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSArray *myOrigan = [_relatedOffers objectAtIndex:pos];
            NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[myOrigan valueForKeyPath:@"offer_image"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL]];
            UIImage *image = [MYUtil imageWithImage:aImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(158, 70)];
            aImage = nil;
            if(image)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [aButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:normal];

                });
            }
        });

    }
    }else{
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_rotateView];
        [_rotate stopAnimating];
    }
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_rotateView];
    [_rotate startAnimating];
    [_relatedViewOffer setHidden:YES];
     _offers =nil;
     _offers = [_relatedOffers objectAtIndex:[button tag]];
    NSArray * allSubviews = [self.relatedViewOffer subviews];
    for(UIView *view in allSubviews)
    {
        if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }    
     [self viewDidLoad];
     [self viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

i am creating horizontal scroll view .In this scroll view buttons are added but upto 7 buttons it is working well after that it is not working ?
please solve this problem.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which bit of code (there is a lot to look at)?

Comment: Did you put break point inside the - (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button{} method? and you need to check whether the button action is calling or not.

Comment: @user3182143 thank u i put break point inside the - (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button{} method it is calling up  to 7 buttons only after it is not calling

Comment: @trojanfoe [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: I have not got what you say.

Comment: @user3182143 it is working fine upto 7 Buttons after that this method is not called  - (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button{}

Comment: Add the following: `self.relatedViewOffer.clipsToBounds = YES;` and figure out if the buttons are still visible. If not, that the buttons are outside of the bounds of `self.relatedViewOffer`. Buttons that are outside of the bounds of its super view don't receive touch events.

Comment: @dasdom how can i check the buttons are still visible or not ?

Comment: @SudheerKumar If you can see them, they are still visible.

Comment: @dasdom i am not seeing ,invisible?

Comment: @dasdom you  are correct .how to solve this? please help me

Comment: Make `self.relatedViewOffer` big enough to fit all buttons. How to do this depends on your UI code. I would use Auto Layout but this is a bit tricky in combination with a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @dasdom it is work .....thank you ..

Comment: I have added an answer. Could you please check it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following: `self.relatedViewOffer.clipsToBounds = YES;` and figure out if the buttons are still visible. If not, that the buttons are outside of the bounds of `self.relatedViewOffer`. Buttons that are outside of the bounds of its super view don't receive touch events.

If you can't see the button, you need to make `self.relatedViewOffer` big enough to fit all buttons.